# Laravel Translatable factory seeding with dynamic locales

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-seeding, laravel-translatable

I want to factory seed a translatable model without hardcoding the locales.

There are two values that I have to seed, slug which is not translatable, and
title which has to be translated to all the languages from the languages table.

Here is the factory file:

```
$factory->define(App\Category::class, function (Faker $faker) {

 $counter = 1;
 $locales = Language::pluck('lang'); //returns hr,en,de
 $titles = [];

 foreach ($locales as $locale) {
    $titles[$locale] = [
        'title' => 'Title for category-' .$counter++. ' on '. $locale . ' language'
    ];
 }

/*
$titles = 
     "hr" => array:1 [
        "title" => "Title for category-1 on hr language"
     ]
     "en" => array:1 [
        "title" => "Title for category-2 on en language"
      ...
 */

return [
    'slug' => 'category-'.$counter++,
    $titles
];
});
```

This gives me an error:

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'hr'

Query created by the factory:

> insert in
>   to `category_translations` (`locale`, `hr`, `en`, `de`, `test`, `category_id`) values (0, Title for category-1 on hr language, Title
>    for category-2 on en language, Title for category-3 on de languag
>   e, Title for category-4 on test language, 20))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experimenting I've found a solution, here it is:

```
$factory->define(App\Category::class, function (Faker $faker) {

 static $counter = 1;
 $locales = Language::pluck('lang');
 $titles = array('slug' => 'CATEGORY-'.$counter);

 foreach ($locales as $locale) {
    $titles[$locale] = [
        'title' => 'Title for category-' .$counter. ' on '. $locale . ' language'
    ];
 }
 $counter++;


return $titles;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution for Laravel 9

```php
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;

/**
 * @extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory<\App\Models\Attribute>
 */
class AttributeFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array<string, mixed>
     */
    public function definition()
    {
        $title = faker_translation('lastName');

        return [
            'title' => $title,
        ];
    }
}
```

`app.php`

```php
'fallback_locale' => 'en',


'faker_locale' => 'lt_LT',

'locales' => [
    'lt' => 'Lietuvių',
    'en' => 'English',
    'ru' => 'Русский',
],

'faker_locales' => [
    'lt' => 'lt_LT',
    'en' => 'en_US',
    'ru' => 'ru_RU',
],
```

`helpers.php`

```php
if (! function_exists('faker_translation')) {
    function faker_translation($property = 'name')
    {
        $fakerLocales = config('app.faker_locales');

        return collect(config('app.locales'))
            ->map(fn ($locale, $key) => faker($fakerLocales[$key])->unique()->$property)
            ->toArray();
    }
}
```

`composer.json`

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
        "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
    },
    "files": [
        "app/helpers.php"
    ]
},
```